# use fftw3 with gfortran included in TDM-GCC-64

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fftw

I am trying to use `FFTW3` with `gfortran` compiler included in the `TDM-GCC-64` suite in Windows 7 platform.

I have downloaded "fftw-3.3.4-dll64.zip" from the following page:

http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

I also created a fortran module described in the following tutorial:

http://www.fftw.org/doc/Defining-an-FFTW-module.html

Now, I tried to compile the following fortrans program

```
program test

use FFTW3 

implicit none

integer N
parameter(N=4)

integer*8 plan
  double complex in, out
  dimension in(N),out(N)

  integer i

  write(*,*) 'Input array:'

  do i = 1,N,1
    in(i) = dcmplx(float(i),float(i+1))
    write(*,*) '    in(',i,') = ',in(i)
  enddo

  call dfftw_plan_dft_1d ( plan, N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE )

  call dfftw_execute ( plan )

  write(*,*) 'Output array:'
  do i = 1,N,1
    write(*,*) '    out(',i,') = ',out(i)
  enddo

  call dfftw_destroy_plan ( plan )

  call dfftw_plan_dft_1d ( plan, N, out, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE )

  call dfftw_execute ( plan )

  write(*,*) 'Output array after inverse FFT:'
  do i = 1,N,1
    write(*,*) '    ',N,' * in(',i,') = ',in(i)
  enddo

  call dfftw_destroy_plan ( plan )

  end
```

I tried to compile but the a couple of error messages popped up:

undefined reference to `dfftw_plan_dft_1d_'
undefined reference to`dfftw_execute_'
...

The command used for compiling is:

gfortran test.f90 -ffree-form -o test_fftw.exe

I searched web up and down but have not found solutions to the problem. Could anyone help me out here? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn [the basics of compiling and linking programs with GCC](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) 
This tutorial refers to the GCC C compiler, `gcc`, and C++ compiler, `g++`, but the principles are the same for the Fortran compiler, `gfortran`.

Your program invokes functions, like `dfftw_plan_dft_1d` that are not defined
in your code but in the `fftw3` library. You must therefore tell `gfortran`
to *link* that library with your program, after it is compiled, or no definitions will be found for
these functions, and no executable can be built. Instead, the linkage
fails with the `undefined reference` errors you are seeing.

The command you have used to build the program:

```
gfortran test.f90 -ffree-form -o test_fftw.exe
```

attempts to compile and link the program in a single command. You can do this,
if you clearly understand the underlying separate processes of compiling
and linking. If you don't, you should follow the better practice of compiling first,
and if that is successful, then linking. The command you have used fails in
its linkage step because it does not tell the linker that the `fftw3` library
is needed (or where to find it) so no attempt is made to find it and link it.

You say you have downloaded `fftw-3.3.4-dll64.zip`. I presume you have
unzipped it somewhere on your system. Let's say you unzipped it to `C:\fftw-3.3.4-dll64`.

You also say you have made an FFTW3 module that apparently is being used successfully. 
In that case, compile your program first:

```
gfortran -c -o test.o test.f90
```

generating an object file `test.o`. The option `-c` tells `gfortran` to compile only,
and not to link. (You do not need to specify `--ffree-form`: the file-extension `.f90`
implies it).

Next, link the object file `test.o` with the `fttw3` library, to make an executable
program `test_fftw.exe`:

```
gfortran -o test_fftw.exe test.o -LC:\fftw-3.3.4-dll64 -lfftw3-3
```

The linker option:

```
-LC:\fftw-3.3.4-dll64
```

tells the linker to add `C:\fftw-3.3.4-dll64` (where you unzipped the package) 
to the list of directories that it will search to find libraries. And the linker option `-lfftw3-3` tells it to link a library that matches the identifier `fftw3-3`. On Windows, the GCC linker
will match a library identfier `name` with any of the filenames:

```
libname.a   (a static library)
libname.dll (a shared library)
name.dll    (also a shared library)
name.lib    (an import library for a shared library)
```

So, since `C:\fftw-3.3.4-dll64` contains the shared library `libfftw3-3.dll`,
the linker will identify it in that directory as the one required by `-lfftw3-3`

Now, unless there are other problems, you program will link and you will have
an executable `test_fftw.exe`, which will run, provided that `libfftw3-3.dll`
can be found, at runtime, in one of [the places where the Windows
loader will look for it.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx)

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me as well. I have one question though, by using the following command as above (gfortran -o test_fftw.exe test.o -LC:\fftw-3.3.4-dll64 -lfftw3-3), Do we implicitly enable multi threads for fftw algorithm ?